# PHP Fatal Error - memory runs out

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have a table data `tb_Agroindustri` with lots of coordinates, i use yii2 with extension yii2-google-maps-library to show it on google maps.
this is my code:

```
foreach ($feederWilayah as $value) {
   $idFeed = $value->id_wilayah;
      $path = Agroindustri::find()
            ->where(['id_wilayah' => $idFeed])
            ->all();

      foreach ($path as $value){
            $koord = new LatLng([
                'lat' => $value->lat,
                'lng' => $value->lng
            ]);
            $coords[] = $koord;
      }

      $polygon = new Polygon([
            'paths' => $coords,
      ]);

      // Add it now to the map
      $map->addOverlay($polygon);
      // end of show polygon
}
```

but i have an error message : `Allowed memory size of xxxxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xx bytes).` Then i'm trying to add this code `ini_set("memory_limit","512M")`. but i still get error.

am i must change my code or how ? is there a way to fix my problem ? if there is could someone could provide a tutorial or something, that would be a real help. i'm going crazy with this.

Comment: Looks like you're performing a database query within a loop, then looping through that result (still in a loop), which means that your processes are going to be exponential in terms of the number of operations - any way you can optimise, i.e. get an array of all the `$idFeeds` then use that to make one `find()` query?

Comment: @scrowler i dont have idea, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try

```
$path = Agroindustri::find()
        ->where(['id_wilayah' => $idFeed])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

or write it with LIMIT. also can help unset variables after if used.